# Google Cloud Speech-to-Text non-intrusive end-user authentication

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-authentication, google-cloud-speech

I am working on a desktop application using GCP Speech-to-Text API to perform streaming recognition.  I'm using Python 3 and Google client libraries, `google.cloud.speech`.  I've started off the [*transcribe streaming infnite Python sample*](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/microphone/transcribe_streaming_infinite.py) and built around those concepts, and everything works nicely.  I'm now trying to get to the end user access question, as I'm currently using a service account file for development purposes, which I'm obviously not willing to distribute to all users.

Basically, how do I give access to my end users to the Speech-to-Text service for streaming recognition in the least intrusive way possible?  I have no need for accessing storage or the like, as I don't access buckets contents and stream all audio directly.  I actually don't need *any* user information, I only need GCP to process the STT requests and send me the responses.

I see 2 solutions that should work on paper, out of the three the documentation mentions (I leave out the service account file ones):

- API key
- OAuth2

### API key

[API keys](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) sound like my dream option: it's simple, doesn't require user interaction past initial setup, I can manage such keys in GCP's console, and it should be able to grant access to what I need (as I effectively don't need any user info, an account is mostly irrelevant).

However, how to use an API key using the Google Speech client library totally eludes me.  I can see [a PUB/SUB Go example](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#api-keys), but I can't find any mapping to Python.  I'm not even 100% sure it can work, as the [Go documentation for the option](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/option?tab=doc#WithAPIKey) seems to note it only works for JSON-over-HTTP, and I believe the client library for Speech-to-Text is using gRPC.

Yet, at least with a JSON non-streaming recognize request, I *can* use such an API key, and successfully did so [manually using cURL on the command-line](https://gist.github.com/cwendling/37b58c76b8b29e2aecab7a5316b0627d).  So I still have a little bit of hope, in case the gRPC restriction either isn't true or doesn't concern my use case.

This part's question would summarize as: "how do I specify an *API key* using the Python `SpeechClient`?".

### OAuth2

This sounds like my second-best option, as it uselessly asks the user for authentication while I don't actually need any personal data.  Yet, I still have serious issues I'm struggling to overcome:

- How do I reliably store info that prevent me from having to re-ask the user for authorization every single time the app runs?  `google_auth_oauthlib`'s `InstalledAppFlow` doesn't seem to provide such feature, so I'm [rolling my own](https://gist.github.com/cwendling/a9fc2d96ac25e515b46bd5526934bf9f) based on `google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials.from_authorized_user_file()` after having saved them with the `to_json()` the first time I obtained them with `InstalledAppFlow`.  I'm however [confident this will not last](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration), and I'm really not sure how to check whether the credentials are still good *before* I fail to use an API with them (e.g. I can't seem to be able to rely on `Credentials.valid` before they actually get used).
- There seem to be no specific Speech-to-Text scopes, and the [required one](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#speech) is way broader than what I need, leading to an overly complex and frightening authorization request.  And no, without this scope I cannot access the Speech-to-Text API, I tried :)

### Summary

To summarize: what is my best and least-intrusive option to provide credentials to be able to use GCP Speech-to-Text in my desktop application?

Comment: To give you some hints. 1) API Keys are legacy and only work with some services. 2) OAuth2 is how authorization is done in GCP. 3) Credentials (OAuth Access Tokens) expire after 3,600 seconds. 4) Invest the time to learn how OAuth works on Google Cloud. This can be challenging if OAuth is new to you. There are lots of examples on the Internet to help with the basics. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks. I already looked at that page on OAuth2 concepts and I think I mostly get the ideas around it, but what I think I have a problem with is understanding how I could use the APIs I have at hand to do some of it – and mainly, handle the case where the refresh token expired.  Is there a library to help me, or should I somehow write a custom OAuth2 management module to handle the corner case where the refresh token expires? What I'm trying to achieve seems fairly common to me for having been solved already a couple of times… I'll keep looking.

Comment: Google OAuth Refresh Tokens do not expire (typically). In the rare case that one becomes invalid, the user must reauthenticate from the beginning. There is no corner case to worry about with Refresh Tokens - they are either valid or not. Perhaps you mean `OAuth Access Tokens`. In that case they must be refreshed every hour. The logic for handling this is simple and well understood. There are lots of tutorials on OAuth. My website has examples even using `curl` to help simplify the process of getting your mind around everything. OAuth is very simple and very complicated depending skillset.

Comment: For what concerns OAuth 2.0 and the persistence of credentials data, please read [my answer to a very much related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64719550/8327971) (though tagged with [tag:youtube-data-api]). I posted there Python 3 code that saves to and loads from a JSON text file the credentials data that results upon OAuth authentication/authorization flow.