# How to bypass entering authentication code to authorize my code everytime I use the YouTube Data API v3

Tags: oauth-2.0, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

So every time I run my code it gives a link on my terminal that I have to manually press on and choose my Gmail account on browser to login and receive an authorization code. That again I have to paste onto my terminal.

Is there a way to skip this process?

The code I'm using:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Sample Python code for youtube.videos.update
# See instructions for running these code samples locally:
# https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#python

import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"

    client_secrets_file = "client_secret_key.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.videos().update(
        part="id,snippet",
        body={
          "id": "videoid",
          "snippet": {
            "title": "XOXOXO",
            "description": "Through IDE",
            "categoryId": "27"
          }
        }
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed there's the possibility to save your `credentials` object the first time running successfully an OAuth authorization/authentication flow; then to load the credentials object from that file each time running the program for the `n`-th time, where `n >= 2`.

Here is how I recommend to structure your code:

```
import os, pickle

from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def pickle_file_name(
        api_name = 'youtube',
        api_version = 'v3'):
    return f'token_{api_name}_{api_version}.pickle'

def load_credentials(
        api_name = 'youtube',
        api_version = 'v3'):
    pickle_file = pickle_file_name(
        api_name, api_version)

    if not os.path.exists(pickle_file):
        return None

    with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as token:
        return pickle.load(token)

def save_credentials(
        cred, api_name = 'youtube',
        api_version = 'v3'):
    pickle_file = pickle_file_name(
        api_name, api_version)

    with open(pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(cred, token)

def create_service(
        client_secret_file, scopes,
        api_name = 'youtube',
        api_version = 'v3'):
    print(client_secret_file, scopes,
        api_name, api_version,
        sep = ', ')

    cred = load_credentials(api_name, api_version)

    if not cred or not cred.valid:
        if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
            cred.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                    client_secret_file, scopes)
            cred = flow.run_console()

    save_credentials(cred, api_name, api_version)

    try:
        service = build(api_name, api_version, credentials = cred)
        print(api_name, 'service created successfully')
        return service
    except Exception as e:
        print(api_name, 'service creation failed:', e)
        return None

def main():
    youtube = create_service("client_secret_key.json",
        ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"])
    if not youtube: return

    request = youtube.videos().update(
        part="id,snippet",
        body={
          "id": "videoid",
          "snippet": {
            "title": "XOXOXO",
            "description": "Through IDE",
            "categoryId": "27"
          }
        }
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You have to be aware of the following peculiarity of the code above: if you run your script the second time from within a different directory than the one from within you've ran it the first time, the script will reinitiate an OAuth flow when that (current) directory does not contain a credentials pickle file.

---

Now, if you have installed (or otherwise are willing to install) the package [Google Authentication Library for Python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python), `google-auth`, version >= 1.21.3 (`google-auth` v1.3.0 introduced `Credentials.from_authorized_user_file`, v1.8.0 introduced `Credentials.to_json` and v1.21.3 fixed this latter function w.r.t. its class' `expiry` member), then you may have your `credentials` object saved to and load from a JSON text file.

Here is the code that'll do that:

```
import os, json, io

...

def json_file_name(
        api_name = 'youtube',
        api_version = 'v3'):
    return f'token_{api_name}_{api_version}.json'

def load_credentials(
        api_name = 'youtube',
        api_version = 'v3'):
    cred_file = json_file_name(
        api_name, api_version)

    if not os.path.exists(cred_file):
        return None

    from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
    return Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(cred_file)

def save_credentials(
        cred, api_name = 'youtube',
        api_version = 'v3'):
    cred_file = json_file_name(
        api_name, api_version)

    with io.open(cred_file, 'w', encoding = 'UTF-8') as json_file:
        json_file.write(cred.to_json())

...
```

Comment: Thank you @stvar ! On the `Youtube Analytics API`... I used your first solution with success in my `deepnote` notebook... I refreshed my kernel and it still worked. Per your comment "You have to be aware of the following peculiarity..." Will that `.pickle` file that is generated work *permanently* (or at least a while until some other random technical issue) or might it not work due to expiration within hours or days. My goal is to do a daily refresh and send the data to a database. I guess I will see if it still works without login when I open my deepnote notebook tomorrow.

Comment: @David Erickson: The stored credentials (either in pickle for JSON format) do expire in certain cases, implying that you'll have to run an OAuth flow again. Specifically, the *refresh token* contained in one such bundle of data could expire. Here is the official specification of this issue: [Refresh token expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration). Note that the refresh tokens of an app with publishing status of *Testing* has a lifespan of only 7 days.

Comment: Thank you @stvar. These are the exact settings that I have set up. `A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.` The `Youtube Analytics API` requires you to use `OAuth` and is the only place for us to currently get Revenue data , so you cannot use a service account or API Key. I was hoping that they lasted longer than 7 days, but this is helpful information.